# jquery check if element exist in val

Tags: jquery, find, element

Why is var x giving 0 length for iframe. I'm trying to check if iframe tag exits inside val.

```
<textarea name="embed">
    <iframe src="http://.."></iframe>
</textarea>

$($('#embedModal textarea').val());
var x = $textareaval.find('iframe').length;
```

I'm able to get a length in the example below for embed.

```
<object><embed></embed></object>
textareaval.find('embed').length;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
$textareaval.find('iframe').andSelf( ).length
```

Comment: why can't find() find it without including andSelf. Does find only search child elements?

Comment: Looking at the APi i see only descendants are considered candidates, isn't iframe decendant of textarea

Comment: @alex - try using `.filter()`: `$textareaval.filter('iframe').length;`

Comment: @karim79 filter doesn't work if iframe is wrapped is another tag. I need to search all elements and child elements of the textarea val to see if iframe is found.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't put HTML tags in a TextArea. Weird/Bad things happen.

For example, these two iframes render completely different in the DOM tree:

```
   <textarea name="embed">   
      <iframe src="http://www.google.com"></iframe> 
    </textarea> 

    <div name="MyDiv">   
      <iframe src="http://www.google.com"></iframe> 
    </div>
```

Comment: I'm using the textarea to allow User to pastes video embed code in the textarea, then i check that value to determine if it's an embed or iframe  tag, do certain things with it accordingly  before i append it to body.